# Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

> Server Error in '/asppub' Application.
>   Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.mis3200_unit4_ringu4l2_2_aspx'
>   does not contain a definition for 'cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged' and
>   no extension method 'cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ASP.mis3200_unit4_ringu4l2_2_aspx' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 112:    </p>
Line 113:    <p>
Line 114:        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblFees" runat="server" 
Line 115:            onselectedindexchanged="cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatLayout="Flow" 
Line 116:            ValidationGroup="L2.2">
```

Source File: c:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\asppub\MIS3200\Unit4\RingU4L2.2.aspx    Line: 114

Comment: Do you have the event `cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged` in your code behind?

Comment: It is common, after using copy&paste pattern :)

Comment: Ha, been there... Either remove "onselectedindexchanged="cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged" from your asp control, or put in an event handler for "cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged" in your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the event handler `cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged` in code behind, if you are not using it simple delete `onselectedindexchanged="cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged"` from the `asp:CheckBoxList` tag.

Usually `asp:CheckBoxList` does not do the `postback` and does not require `selectedindexchanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error is coming because, the compiler is trying to find out the event handler or method namely cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged. Seems like you have not added this in your aspx.cs class. If you are not using it delete it from the code else define the handler for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the `cblFees_SelectedIndexChanged` in your code behind, delete it from the checkbox tag. Then click in between the quotes of your `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and press `Ctrl_Spce` in your keyboard. It shows you a list of events. Choose `New event` from it. The event will be created in your code behind.
[image]